# Set arbitrary base of logarithm in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I would like to ask how can I set arbitrary base of logarithm in gnuplot (I would need `f(x)=x^{1+9log2(x)}` function to plot).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like there are only builtin functions for the natural `log` and `log10`. But you can easily [change the base](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithm#Change_of_base) of the logarithm.

```
log_b(x) = log_k(x) / log_k(b)
```

Thus, you can rewrite your formula as

```
f(x) = x**(1 + 9 * log(x)/log(2))
```

Answer (score 3):

To expand upon the answer of tobias_k, you can create a [user-defined](http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/docs_4.2/node60.html) function which takes the base as a secondary argument:

```
logb(x, base) = log(x)/log(base)
```

And then rewrite your formulas as:

```
f(x) = x**(1 + 9 * logb(x, 2))
```